# OpenCV C API not allowing camera release and reopening

Tags: c++, c, opencv, ubuntu

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 and openCV 2.4.9 in a new computer.

I had a working code that, at some point, closes the last cvVideoCapture and opens another, that may or may not have a different index:

```
CvCapture* capture;
capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(1);

...

cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
```

This code used to work flawlessly with Ubuntu 12.0.4 and OpenCV 2.4.? (I'm not sure which version but it was an older one from one year ago). Now it outputs the error

```
HIGHGUI ERROR: V4L: device /dev/video0: Unable to open for READ ONLY
```

On the other hand, the equivalent with the C++ API works:

```
VideoCapture cap;
cap.open(1);

...

cap.release();
cap.open(0);
```

Comment: Documentation says 'In C API, when you finished working with video, release CvCapture structure with `cvReleaseCapture()`, ...' http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-videocapture

Comment: I will give it a try and remove all cvReleaseCapture()

Comment: Why you want to remove them? As the docs state, you should use `cvReleaseCapture()` for `CvCapture` instances. Maybe `cvRelease` should also work, but the docs are unclear about that.

Comment: I have looked into the opencv source, but didn't find relevant changes between 2.4 and 2.4.9. But there was a big change from 2.4.9 to 3.0.0. Does it work, if you open your camera with `ID = 0` also at the beginning, e.g. `capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);` in second line?

Answer (score 0):

You can use different names for each camera device open.Like below code.Try this.

```
 VideoCapture cap,cap1;
    cap.open(1);

    ...

    cap.release();
    cap1.open(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

After some experiments I'm sure, that `cvRelease` is definitely not for freeing a `CvCapture` instance. I'm getting a compiler warning about different pointer types. Maybe you should compile with some additional flags. You definitely have to use `cvReleaseCapture(&capture)`, like stated in the docs. I'm not sure if that's the solution for your problem, maybe you need to give some more information.

```
CvCapture* capture;
capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(1);

cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
```